# Windows Server 2019 IIS SMTP

Tags: email, smtp, windows-server-2019

I've added the SMTP feature to my Windows Server as every tutorial on the Internet does and restarted IIS.
But I can't see the SMTP virtual server under my sites:

[image: Image of the issue here]

What's wrong?
Is there any problem with SMTP and Windows Server 2019?

More general question:
How can I set up a mail server on my Windows Server 2019?

Comment: And what exactly are these "every tutorial on the Internet"? Which tutorial were you following? Was it for IIS 10?

Comment: @EsaJokinen https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bFmCMVqBJAI
https://contabo.com/blog/install-e-mail-server-windows/
https://support.hostway.com/hc/en-us/articles/360002248059-How-to-Set-Up-An-Internal-SMTP-Service-For-Windows-Server
https://www.hivelocity.net/kb/how-do-i-install-iis-smtp/
and much more....

Comment: Well, the YouTube video is about MailEnable, not the SMTP server feature of Windows Server. The other links are quite old: tutorials for Windows NT/2000/XP may not necessarily work for Windows Server 2019... The Hostway tutorial for 2012 is close, and it actually answers your question: the feature shouldn't appear on this IIS manager...

Comment: BTW, as an additional advice, you shouldn't be exposing your RDP to the world... See e.g. https://www.welivesecurity.com/2019/12/17/bluekeep-time-disconnect-rdp-internet/ & https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2019/07/17/rdp-exposed-the-wolves-already-at-your-door/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Every tutorial on the Internet* I could find have this in common: installing the IIS 6 Management Compatibility.

[image: Add features that are required for SMTP Server?]

### The SMTP service is configured using the IIS 6.0 Manager!

- [Chris Lazari: Creating an SMTP Service on Windows Server 2016](https://chrislazari.com/creating-an-smtp-service-on-microsoft-windows-server-2016/):

  > In fact, Windows Server 2016 still uses IIS 6 tools to host and manage
  > the SMTP service. This is truly remarkable that a fundamental service
  > like SMTP has not been changed for at least the last 13 years. The old
  > adage of, ‘If it isn’t broken, do not fix it’ comes to mind.
- [Umesh Dubey: How to configure SMTP server in Windows server 2016](https://www.znetlive.com/blog/how-to-configure-smtp-server-in-windows-server-2016/):

  > Launch the Internet Information Services (IIS) 6.0 Manager.
  >
  > [image: Internet Information Services (IIS) 6.0 Manager]
- [Tali Smith: Configure SMTP E-Mail in IIS 7](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-on-iis/configure-smtp-e-mail-in-iis-7-and-above) (Windows Server 2008 & R2):

  > You need to step through the entire wizard again, even though IIS is
  > already installed (IIS 6 Management Compatibility and the IIS 6
  > Management Console must be installed for SMTP to work).
- Even the [How to Set Up An Internal SMTP Service For Windows Server](https://support.hostway.com/hc/en-us/articles/360002248059-How-to-Set-Up-An-Internal-SMTP-Service-For-Windows-Server) (2012) you used has:

  > From the Search charm, type IIS. Hover your mouse over one of the
  > selections, and run the Internet Information Services (IIS) 6.0
  > Manager.

  > 3. Expand to SMTP Virtual Server #1, right click and select Properties.
  >
  > [image: SMTP Virtual Server #1]

### This may change soon...

Now, [Features removed or planned for replacement starting with Windows Server, version 1709](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/get-started/removed-features-1709) suggests IIS 6 Management compatibility is going to be removed. I don't know what will happen to the SMTP service after that. Maybe it will be removed, too, or arranged differently, and then this answer becomes obsole.

### How can I set up a mail server on my Windows Server 2019?

- Microsoft has [Exchange Server 2019](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/exchange-team-blog/exchange-server-2019-now-available/ba-p/608610). According to [Exchange Server supportability matrix](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/plan-and-deploy/supportability-matrix?view=exchserver-2019), the Exchange 2019 is the only Exchange version supported on Windows Server 2019.
- There are also free alternatives, e.g. these [recommendations from Milan Stanojevic](https://windowsreport.com/free-mail-server-windows-10/).

Comment: Thank you!
That worked... I was missing the "IIS 6 manager" part...
Now I can configure the SMTP BUT:
That's not what I was thinking :(
I was searching for how can I make email service on my domain. Sth like: admin@mydomain.com...
And search results lead me to SMTP... But its not the thing that I was looking for... is it?
It just relaying emails to the destination.

Comment: Yes, SMTP is a protocol that does only that: delivers email. It doesn't implement mailbox storage nor reading mail using a *mail user agent*, which is a job for e.g. the IMAP protocol. The last part of my answer is a good start in finding fully featured email server software. Although it might not be a good idea, as maintaining own email server is a lot more complex task than maintaining e.g. a web server.

Comment: I want the email for an SSL certificate... They said that I should have an admin@myDomain.com email...so u think I should use one of those free mail servers?

Comment: Can't you use Let's Encrypt? See e.g. [Install Let’s Encrypt with IIS on Windows Server 2019](https://www.snel.com/support/how-to-install-lets-encrypt-with-iis-on-windows-server-2019/) and [Using Let's Encrypt with IIS on Windows](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/feb/22/using-lets-encrypt-with-iis-on-windows).